# SQLite Android Project and Android Library

Tags: android

I have the following ones:

- One main Android application.
- One Android library project.

The main project adds the library project.
The problem is, I need same Database and same data model for both apps. I need access same tables of the database and I also need the same data model cause there is data I need to share between each other.

Can anyone explain me how can I do it??

Thanks a lot!!

Comment: question is why in this case you divide your project to app and library ... what is the purpose of the library project in your case ?

Comment: Cause of the requeriments of the project I need to create it like library and I need "more or less" independent development teams......I know it seems weird, but it has to be that way....

Comment: Having disjunct development teams is common practice these days. And, I don't mean this in a hash way at all, but its really not an excuse for poor software design.

Comment: That answer doesn´t help. Thanks anyway........